# Sorting an array of ranges for display

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have an array of ranges with start and end timestamps. I want to display those ranges on a graph.

Right now, my naive algorithm gets an array of ranges sorted by their start timestamp and

- iterate over each range in the sorted array

  - find the first bucket where the last range of the bucket has an end timestamp lower than the start timestamp of the current sample

    - If no such bucket exists, add a new bucket
  - add current sample to found bucket

I then use these buckets to fill my graph. Each bucket represents a line on the graph.

[image]

It's a O(n²) algorithm. This works fine for my needs, if not a bit slow when having 50,000+ ranges.

One issue with this algorithm is when a range's end timestamp changes, the algorithm needs to be run for all samples.

For whatever reason, I now want to make a change to how the data is fetched from the database, and due to technical constraints, the data cannot be sorted efficiently.

Please help me think of an efficient algorithm where data does not have to be sorted.

Comment: what are the requirements for your graph?

Comment: To display the ranges in a compact manner.

Comment: you want the least lines possible?

Comment: Vertical lines, yes. All ranges should be drawn.

Comment: sounds like the job scheduling problem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem**

You have a set of ranges, in the fewest number of lines, display each range so that intersecting/adjacent ranges are on different lines.

**Natural Buckets**

Based on the description ranges fall into natural buckets. That is the only ranges that mater are those that are adjacent to or intersect with itself.

1. Pick a range
2. If it intersects/adjoins a pre-existing bucket.

   - Add the range to the bucket and extend the left/right edge of the bucket.
   - Keep the ranges within the bucket sorted by either the left or right edge.
   - If the left/right edge of the bucket shifts check for and merge with the prior/next bucket if it now adjoins/intersects (merging is a simple concatenation of the sorted contents).
3. If it does not intersect/adjoin a pre-existing bucket.

   - Create a new bucket with the same left/right edge as the range.
   - Keep these buckets sorted by their left/right edge (which does not mater as they do not overlap/touch).

This makes something similar to an R*-Tree where each leaf node represents a set of intersecting/adjoining ranges, and leaf-sibling represent the buckets. The nodes above are helpers for efficiently sorting new ranges into the structure.

If the ranges were already presorted by the left and/or right edge, the algorithm can be simplified. If ordered by the left edge:

1. Pick the first range, note this range as the start of the partition.
2. Skip any range whose right edge is less than or equal to the picked range's right edge.
3. If a range has a right edge greater than the picked range's right edge, and it intersects/adjoin the picked range.

   - pick this new range, but *do not* set it as the start of the partition
   - Resume at step 2.
4. If a range has a right edge greater than the picked range's right edge, and it does not intersect/adjoin the picked range.

   - all ranges from the partition start to the range prior to this range form a partition.
   - Pick this range, note this range as the start of the partition.
   - Resume at step 2.
5. If no range is greater

   - all ranges from the partition start to the end form a partition.

If each bucket contains one range, great display a single line with each range.

**Back to the original Problem**

*Except we now know that every range in the bucket intersects or adjoins with another range in the bucket, and there are N buckets which do not intersect/adjoin each other.*

The buckets now are for all intents and purposes independent problems. How many lines a given bucket needs in order to layout, or how it is layed out does not rely on any other bucket. Solving how each lays out its ranges can be parallelised.

Unfortunately each bucket is still a problem, but worse now because each range within is known to have the intersection/adjoinment property (when the bucket holds 2+ ranges). It is not certain that a single range could be removed that would break this property and allow the bucket to be divided up into smaller buckets. Certainly removing some K ranges would allow this to happen, but again there is no guarantee that K is not N the total number of ranges in the bucket. Obviously another solution is needed.

That being said, if a given range consumes most of the space, it might be presumable that removing it would reduce the number of intersections/adjoinments among the remaining ranges. As the problem is also a visualisation issue, this might make sense as you may have a threshold above which such ranges should be displayed in a particular order. I'm not going to travel down this path, but it would not be too hard to extend the line generation algorithm to assimilate these so as to display the least number of lines necessary.

**Lines**

One way to convert the bucket into lines is to give each range a line. This does not guarantee the least number of lines, but it is certainly the most lines that can be used to display all applicable ranges. You could imagine that two lines would settle/merge when they don't have overlapping/adjoining ranges, and simply repeat until no more lines could settle. This would give fewer lines, but would not guarantee the least. Why? because it might be possible to merge lines in such a way that makes merging further impossible, but had they been merged differently would allow more merges to occur. Consider:

```
1: ----|  |---|          |-------
2: -----|        |---------| |---
3:           |------|
```

Had line 1's 2nd range been merged into line 2 instead, line 3 could have been merged into line 1.

```
1: ----|     |------|    |-------
2: -----| |---|  |---------| |---
```

The least number of lines required, would be the same as the point which has the most intersecting/adjoining ranges. That could be established by uniquely listing the points that make up each range, and tallying the number of intersecting/adjoining ranges. The largest Tally is the least number of lines needed. In the above example, you can see that no point intersects/adjoins more than 2 ranges.

In fact this hints at an efficient algorithm.

1. Take the left most range (if there are several, just pick one maybe pick the longest), assign this range to the first line.
2. Pick the next left-most range, find an existing line whose right is not intersecting/adjoining the left of the range.

   - If found append the range to the line, as the new range does not justify a new line and because it is the next leftmost and was the only candidate that might justify a new line here.

     - For visual pleasantness if several candidate lines exist pick the one with the most ranges/most points encompased/etc... whichever heuristic makes sense.
   - If not found then add this range to a new line, as all the current lines have ranges on their right the intersect/adjoin.
3. repeat step 2.

**Algorithm Complexity**

This produces a O(KN) algorithm where K is the max number of lines, and N is the number of ranges, presuming already sorted data. You might be able to play that down by sorting the lines by their right edge reducing the K aspect to near constant, but at the cost resorting the updated line, so I am uncertain about the trade-off there.

The natural bucket technique above is a O(NlogN) algorithm when operating on unsorted ranges, but if the ranges where already sorted by left, or by right could be reduced to a linear O(N) algorithm. Whether or not this partitioning would pay off depends on the K (total lines) versus the N (total ranges) versus the sorted state of the ranges. If the ranges are already sorted (by left or right edge) then its a K vs logN question, if K is expected to be less than LogN go with a straight line construction, otherwise partition first, and assemble the lines per bucket (line merging is trivial O(N)). If the data is not sorted, the cost is O(NlogN) either way, might as well sort into sorted buckets as at least then you'll be reducing K to its absolute minimum per bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think my algorithm, described in the question, is the algorithm described in your answer.

Comment: Does seem like I arrived at your algorithm by deduction. I think however the first step of breaking the easy problem apart via partitions to reduce the complexity of the hard problem is the difference.

Comment: I am not sure. Complexity remains O(NK), where K <= N, so O(N²) at worst. Seems to me like the two algorithms are very similar.
My problem is the need to insert unsorted ranges without the need to sort them first (for technical limitations).

Comment: Further analyse, K contributes time effort when reordering the line set by right edge, to place the lines with the least/most right edge in O(1) access locations, so that each of the N ranges can choose to create a new line or append to an existing line in O(1). The update to keep the line sorting could be done in O(logK). Therefor my original analyse is wrong, the algorithm is in fact O(NlogK) when composing lines and keeping them sorted. A line heap would amortise line update and new line operations by leveraging the algorithms progressive streaming nature.